# ESC character in CDATA section

Tags: php, simplexml, libxml2

I compose XML for the API of a clueless provider where some text goes inside a CDATA section (using CDATA is mandatory). I've now been instructed to insert a control character in that field: [ASCII `ESC` aka `U+001B`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001b/index.htm).

As far as I know ESC is [invalid in XML 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML#XML_1.0) and [restricted and highly discouraged in XML 1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML#XML_1.1).

My tests show that:

- `U+001B` in an XML 1.0 document makes it malformed.
- None of my tools (SimpleXML, Firefox, online validators...) seem to support XML 1.1 at all. E.g.:

  > PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser warning : Unsupported version '1.1'

Is what my provider asking for even possible?

Comment: FYI, I composed an XML 1.1 document with a text editor just to find that provider's API doesn't support it at all (not really a surprise). My enquiry has been escalated to "higher level support"... *sigh*